# What is the minimum Android API level is required while connecting with Oracle database using JDBS14.jar

Tags: java, android, oracle, android-studio, jdbc

i am developing an Android application and want to connect to oracle database using JDBC14.jar.
when i build the app it works very efficiently on API level 23 . but its not getting the data when i run it of Api level 19.
so what is the minimum api level required for JDBC14.jar?
And which JDBC level compatible with android api level 19.

Comment: You should **not** access a database system directly from an Android device, it will be unsafe, and likely perform badly over mobile networks. Use a REST webservice (or other form of webservice) to mediate between your Android application and the database.

Comment: Thanks ! but have develop half of my app, if i go for a web service have to change a lot.it also take much time. kindly suggest me the solution with give conditions. 
JDBC14 is not run on lower API levels like 16,19 etc. it work good on API level 25.

Comment: kindly give some helping material to make a REST web service.

Comment: The web is full with resource on creating REST web services.